# How to replace NaN value with zero in a huge data frame?

Tags: r, replace

I tried to replace `NaN` values with zeros using the following script:

```
rapply( data123, f=function(x) ifelse(is.nan(x),0,x), how="replace" )
# [31]   0.00000000  -0.67994832   0.50287454   0.63979527   1.48410571  -2.90402836
```

The NaN value was showing to be zero but when I typed in the name of the data frame and tried to review it, the value was still remaining NaN.

```
data123$contri_us
# [31]          NaN  -0.67994832   0.50287454   0.63979527   1.48410571  -2.90402836
```

I am not sure whether the `rapply` command was actually applying the adjustment in the data frame, or just replaced the value as per shown.

Any idea how to actually change the `NaN` value to zero?

Comment: You can't just do `data123[is.nan(data123)] <- 0`?

Comment: I tried but R gave the the following error message: > Error in is.nan(data123) : default method not implemented for type 'list'

Comment: Hong Ooi's solution works with matrices, but, sadly, not data frames.

Answer (score 127):

It would seem that `is.nan` doesn't actually have a method for data frames, unlike `is.na`. So, let's fix that!

```
is.nan.data.frame <- function(x)
do.call(cbind, lapply(x, is.nan))

data123[is.nan(data123)] <- 0
```

Comment: Your bottom function should be "is.nan.data.frame".

Comment: @Dombey That isn't required; by the magic of method dispatch, `is.nan.data.frame` will be called automatically.

Comment: Can someone explain why the first two lines are written, logically only the third line is required right?

Answer (score 43):

In fact, in R, this operation is very easy:

If the matrix 'a' contains some NaN, you just need to use the following code to replace it by 0:

```
a <- matrix(c(1, NaN, 2, NaN), ncol=2, nrow=2)
a[is.nan(a)] <- 0
a
```

If the data frame 'b' contains some NaN, you just need to use the following code to replace it by 0:

```
#for a data.frame: 
b <- data.frame(c1=c(1, NaN, 2), c2=c(NaN, 2, 7))
b[is.na(b)] <- 0
b
```

Note the difference `is.nan` when it's a matrix vs. `is.na` when it's a data frame.

Doing

```
#...
b[is.nan(b)] <- 0
#...
```

yields: `Error in is.nan(b) : default method not implemented for type 'list'` because b is a data frame.

Note: Edited for small but confusing typos

Comment: This explanation is _wrong_. A NA is not the data frame equivalent of a NaN.

Comment: Wrong answer. Agreed.

Comment: This answer is applicable when you are dealing only with numbers and NaN, or if you want to treat NA as NaN, because is.na(NaN) == TRUE.

Answer (score 29):

The following should do what you want:

```
x <- data.frame(X1=sample(c(1:3,NaN), 200, replace=TRUE), X2=sample(c(4:6,NaN), 200, replace=TRUE))
head(x)
x <- replace(x, is.na(x), 0)
head(x)
```

Answer (score 20):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. I've generated sample data with both `NaN` and `NA`. The first column is fully complete.

```
df <- tibble(x = LETTERS[1:5],
             y = c(1:3, NaN, 4),
             z = c(rep(NaN, 3), NA, 5))

df

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  x         y     z
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1   NaN
2 B         2   NaN
3 C         3   NaN
4 D       NaN    NA
5 E         4     5
```

Then we can apply `mutate_all` with `replace` to the dataframe:

```
df %>% 
   mutate_all(~replace(., is.nan(.), 0))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  x         y     z
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     0
2 B         2     0
3 C         3     0
4 D         0    NA 
5 E         4     5
```

We've replaced `NaN` values with zero and touched neither `NA` values nor the `x` column.

**UPDATE to `dplyr 1.0.0`**

Since the `mutate_all` is deprecated we can now rewrite the expression using `across()` like following:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace(.x, is.nan(.x), 0)))

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  x         y     z
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     0
2 B         2     0
3 C         3     0
4 D         0    NA
5 E         4     5
```