# R openxlsx package. writing NA as blanks?

Tags: r, excel, na

I'm using the openxlsx package to read and write Excel files.

I've noticed that when I export the table to Excel with 
write.xlsx(MyData, file="MyFile.xlsx")
**NAs** appear as **#NUM!** when the file is opened on Excel.

Is there any option to export it just as blanks?
I've being googling and tried options such as  showNA or keepNA but they don't seem to have any effect.

Comment: If no parameter is found in that package, you could use another excel writing package or convert the NA values to blanks with something like `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- "";x})`

Comment: I can't understand the downvote.  I thought some people would know how to do it, it could be impportant and useful for other users.
I've asked on openxlsx github and if it doesn't exist that option I will send a ferature request.

Answer (score 10):

I can't understand the downvote. I thought some people would know how to do it using just an option, without the need of manually tansforming every NA.

As I think it could be important and useful for other users I've also asked on openxlsx's github development page and they replied:

```
 https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/108#issuecomment-125142950
```

In case anybody is interested, if you update to the dev version with

```
 devtools::install_github("awalker89/openxlsx")
```

you will get support for this feature.

the default behaviour now is converting NAs to blanks
And if we want to have #N/A we must use the option keepNA = TRUE 
the option keepNA = TRUE keeps the #N/A

```
require('openxlsx')
df <- head(iris)
df[2,3] <- NA
df[2,5] <- NA
df[3,5] <- NaN
openXL(write.xlsx(df, file = tempdir()))
```

[image]

```
 require('openxlsx')
 df <- head(iris)
 df[2,3] <- NA
 df[2,5] <- NA
 df[3,5] <- NaN
 openXL(write.xlsx(df, file = tempdir(), keepNA = TRUE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Good question!  One I've been looking at as well.  I believe that the default behavior IS to output the `NA` values as blanks.  However, as you show in your example code you have both `NA` and `NaN` values.  The presence of one or more `NaN` values in a column will result in all `NA` and `NaN` values in that column showing up in Excel as `#NUM!`.

To fix this, replace all instances of `NaN` in your file with `NA` prior to exporting the file:

`df[is.na(df)] = NA`

Note the use of `is.na` rather than `is.nan` when x is a data.frame.

See: [How to replace NaN value with zero in a huge data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142117/how-to-replace-nan-value-with-zero-in-a-huge-data-frame)

Answer (score 0):

Creating the workbook before saving it works for me:

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
writeData(wb, 1, keepNA = T, df)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "keepNA.xlsx")
```