# Covert NaN to zero in R code

Tags: r, sum, nan

This is part of my R code:

```
for (i in 1:n) {

...

Smw[i]<-(mw[i]-Emw[i])/(Vmw[i]^(0.5)

...

}
```

and I get this output

```
>Smw
 [1] 1.4205658 1.4357139 0.6331807 0.5006390 1.0186496 0.7762059 0.7129556 1.2702147 0.9721943
[10] 1.1156639 0.6908741 0.9994839 0.4976403 0.6265969 0.8362247 0.9150794 1.4028611 1.8190172
[19] 1.4290714 1.2475859 1.2874732 1.0358361 0.7494117 0.4077862 0.7082040 0.6408069 0.5158288
[28] 0.8990276 1.3660975 0.9901475 1.3291363 1.5966929 1.3004625 1.6013889 1.8312262 1.8797908
[37] 1.4265688 1.2947859 1.2763606 0.7276069 0.1641367 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[46] 0.5363989 0.8374326 0.4455664 1.4205658       **NaN**
```

and I want to proceed the with

```
ooc=Cplus>5

lenOOC = sum(ooc)

lenOOC
```

I couldn't get the `sum(ooc)` since there is a **NaN** in my data. How can I convert the NaN to zero? My Smw data might contain negative values so `max()` is not suitable.

Comment: `Smw[is.nan(Smw)] <- 0`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142117/how-to-replace-nan-value-with-zero-in-a-huge-data-frame/18143097

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple to fix with a base R one liner using the `is.na` function to index the vector

```
Smw[is.na(Smw)] <- 0
```

This will make your summing work. However, it might be more appropriate to retain your `NaN` as this may be useful information later. Perhaps it is therefore better to use `na.rm` inside the `sum` function so that you are not irreversibly modifying information.

```
sum(Smw, na.rm = TRUE)
```

For example:

```
> x <- c(2, 8, NaN)
> sum(x)
NaN
> sum(x, na.rm = T)
10
> x
  2   8 NaN
```