# R - convert Nan to NA

Tags: r, nan, na

I have a dataframe that has Nans in some columns. How do I convert the nans in all columns into NAs?

I've tried `df[is.nan(df)]<-NA` but it shows this error:

```
Error in is.nan(df) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this, if you need to, [as explained in this answer by @Hong-Ooi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18143097/1329484):

```
is.nan.data.frame <- function(x)
  do.call(cbind, lapply(x, is.nan))

df[is.nan(df)] <- NA
```

Is looks a bit strange, because you are creating a function you are not calling, and this is called [Method Dispatch](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html), see the comment by @Hong-Ooi in the answer above.